# What was Cotton Hill's job in the military?

Tags: character, king-of-the-hill

I understand that Cotton Hill from *King of the Hill* killed 50 men, but what was his actual job in the military? Army infantry?

Comment: Cotton states in a sixth season episode that he served with the U.S. Army's 77th Infantry Division.

Comment: Colonel by the time he died. but the series also showed him as a private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cotton Hill was in the Army's 77th Infantry Division and rose to the rank of Colonel.

Sourced from [Wikia](http://kingofthehill.wikia.com/wiki/Cotton_Hill):

> Cotton states in a sixth season episode that he served with the U.S.
>   Army's 77th Infantry Division.

See also [this site on the 77th Infantry Division](http://www.history.army.mil/html/forcestruc/cbtchron/cc/077id.htm).